# How to build a vue form as a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to make a vue component that allows user to create or edit a mailing address. The component I have so far looks like this (simplified)...

```
<template>
<v-container>
  <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
    <v-text-field 
      v-bind:value="address.street"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      label="Number and Street">
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</v-container>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  name: 'address-form',
  props: ['address'],
  // other stuff
}
</script>
```

The parent of this gets a bigger object from the store, and feeds the address as a prop like this...

```
<p>Just to test: {{outerObject.address.street}}</p>
<address-form address="outerObject.address" v-on:changed-address="changedAddress" />
```

And in the script...

```
computed: {
  outerObject () {
    let id = this.$route.query.id
    let outerObject = this.outerObjects.find(o => o.id === id)
    return (outerObject) ? outerObject : this.newOuterObject
  },
  ...mapGetters(['outerObjects'])
```

But two things go wrong:

(1) even though I can see that outerObject is properly initialized in the parent component (I can see the `outerObject.address.street` just fine), the form's street input has no initial value.

(2) If I type anything into that form input, I get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'value' of undefined"

The only place 'value' appears is in reference to the input. But it's my understanding that `value` is a property of the input (and of `$event.target`).  I've tried changing value to street, and various permutations, but my guesses have been all wrong so far.

My aim is to have "two-way binding" between the inputs on the form component and the `outerObject` on the parent, so when user performs edits on the form, the `outerObject` is changed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `address=""` to `v-bind:address=""`, as you are passing in an object reference, instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed the first problem, but I still get the error about "value" when typing into the input.

Answer (score 0):

Two way binding is reached using the following strategy:

1. add `value` as one of your `props` array.
2. add `v-on:change` on the input field inside your component.
3. on change you should emit the change as following `this.$emit('input', newValue)`.

Now you can use your component: `<address-comp v-model='outerObject.address'></address-comp>`

Comment: I took these steps exactly, so now the component props are ['address','value'], changed `v-on:input...` to `v-on:change="this.$emit('input', newValue)"`, and changed the address prop to v-model as you suggest on the parent component.  Now I get the error "cannot read property street of undefined"

Comment: You do not need an `address` prop any more and also tje second parameter of the emit should be the changed value of the text field which is $event.target.value.